# Vuetify JS - Apply CSS to a specific component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Let's say I have a Test.vue with 2 v-text-field components.

I want to apply my CSS only to the first text field.

**Test.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="test">
    <v-text-field></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field></v-text-field>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>


<style scoped>
.v-text-field {
  width: 100px;
}

.v-text-field >>> input {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
}

.v-text-field--outlined >>> fieldset {
  color: #000000 !important;
}
</style>>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about to use the first-child CSS selector

```
<style scoped>
.test:first-child {
  width: 100px;
}

.test:first-child >>> input {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
}

.test:first-child .v-text-field--outlined >>> fieldset {
  color: #000000 !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Okay, but if it's meant for the second child or the 100th child?

Comment: :first-child  === just the first child
:nth-child(n) for nth child

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but I think it would be best to simply give your specific text field an id and reference that.

```html
<div class="test">
    <v-text-field id="my-text-field"></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field></v-text-field>
</div>
```

```css
#my-text-field {
    //your styling
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but how does that work with the styles I mentioned above?

Comment: Can't you simply replace `.v-text-field` with `#my-text-field`? Or does that not work?

Comment: Also note that if you want to use Raeisi's solution for any nth child. There happens to be a [nth child selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: If you are trying to change the text color of the text that the user writes in v-text-field, just put it in the first-level css. You don't need to use deep selectors `>>>`

Comment: Thanks. The n-th child solution does work, although I don't like it because you have to adjust the n when adding components above your text field.

Comment: Try putting all of your styling in #my-text-field {}